# ngx-mask - Simple Decimal Mask Not working

Tags: angular, ngx-mask

I would like a textbox that allows only 2 decimals.  I am using  https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/ to achieve this.

[This example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mask-decimal-jgjdfm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) ( using Angular 8 and an older mask version ) works , but looks like the newer version doesnt!

This is my html:

```
<input type="text" mask="99999999999999.00">
```

**Error repro :**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mask-9g3gqs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

[image]

NOTE:  I have logged a [defect](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/issues/848) in the repo, but was hoping someone in SO can also guide me in case Im missing something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is a bug coming from the package you can open the issue in GitHub,

But for now you can use several workarounds.

1. **Use early versions of the package**
   for example `8.2.x`. The command for installing the old version of this package `npm i ngx-mask@8.x`
2. **or use mask by this way**

```
<input type="text"  mask="separator.2" thousandSeparator="" separatorLimit="99999999999999">
```

Here is the stackblitz example with the second solution
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mask-juzncf?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This is not working with angular 15

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to limit the number of numbers before the decimal point, you can use this mask: `0*.00`.

See [other examples here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)